# Creating a circle point by point

Tags: python

I want to create an array of points that has equal distance to some center coordinate.
It will be like, give to the function center longitude, center latitude, radius of the circle and number of points, then it creates that many points from the center.
How can i do this.
It would be great if anyone helps in Python but any other programming languages are fine.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The set of points at equal distance $R$ from point $C(a,b)$ is the **circle** with center $C$ and radius $R$. Then take points with coordinates $(a+R*\cos(t),b+R*\sin(t))$ for any value of $t$.

Comment: No. When i did this, i get an ellipsoid in google maps. Since they are degrees, not cartesian.